# Proper way to detect that a UWP app is running on a small-screen device (phone)

Tags: c#, screen-orientation, uwp

Having read about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30055312/is-there-a-correct-recommended-way-of-detecting-my-uwp-app-im-running-on-a-phon), I feel there is still an un-answered question about detecting whether a UWP app is running on a device where it would be appropriate to display in portrait only.

The optimal page layouts for our UWP app are such that on a phone, it's best that we disable landscape mode (we don't need such a restriction for larger format devices). What would be the best-practice approach to accomplish this?

Comment: Kind of backwards isn't it?  The smaller the screen, the easier it is to turn.  Use the DisplayInformation class.

Answer (score 17):

You can detect the device family using `AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily`.

```
if(AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily == "Windows.Mobile") {
    // It's a phone
}
else {
    // It's not a phone
}
```

Comment: Simple and efficient method. +1.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if ((Window.Current.Bounds.Width < 640) && (Window.Current.Bounds.Height < 550))
                {
                          //Do something
                }
```

Best of luck .

Answer (score 1):

You can also test with hardware buttons availability , but not every phone has them !

```
public  Platform DetectPlatform()
        {
            bool isHardwareButtonsAPIPresent = ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons");

            if (isHardwareButtonsAPIPresent)
            {
                return Platform.WindowsPhone;
            }
            else
            {
                return Platform.Windows;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the hardware back button.
        Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons")

Comment: what is the surface tablet in this case? Phone or Desktop?